# How to display a preview value on mat-select Angular Material

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I am trying to create a compilation table where I have to select a value in from a mat-select.

[image]

In the third column I have a list of values ​​that I can choose

```
lunch:infoLunch[]=[{id_lunch: '',desc_lunch:''},
                     {id_lunch: 'TP1',desc_lunch:'Normale'},
                     {id_lunch: 'TP2',desc_lunch:'Senza carne'},
                     {id_lunch: 'TP3',desc_lunch:'Senza carne di maiale'},
                     {id_lunch: '14/1020',desc_lunch:'14/1020'}
  ];
```

And this is the html code of the column

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="pasto">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descrizione Pasto</th>
      <td mat-cell  *matCellDef="let studente">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select [disabled]="studente.isAbsent || studente.isGuest" (selectionChange)="checkCheckPastovalue($event, studente)" panelClass="example-panel-dark-blue">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let cust of lunch"
                        [value]="cust"> {{studente.isAbsent || studente.isGuest ?  '': cust.desc_lunch}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

I have an external json from db with set or empty values

```
    {
                      "idStudenti": 1,
                        "nome": "John",
                        "cognome": "Doe",
                        "isChecked": true,
                        "CodLunch": "TP1",
                        "DescLunch": "Normale",
                        "isGuest": false,
                        "hostSchool": "",
                        "isAbsent": false
                    },
                    {
                        "idStudenti": 2,
                        "nome": "Giada",
                        "cognome": "Doe",
                        "isChecked": false,
                        "CodLunch": "",
                        "DescLunch": "",
                        "isGuest": false,
                        "hostSchool": "",
                        "isAbsent": false
                    }
```

How can I display the current value of the json on the mat-select?

Comment: <mat-select [(ngModel)]="yourVariable">...</mat-select>

Answer (score 0):

You got two options for this:

- Use [expandable rows](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-expandable-rows) to display the selected information within the table

--- OR ---

- Have a property and bind it so that you can display the information outside the table in a nice format

Comment: Hey, hope you are doing well, just want to mention that you should include some information about the external link you have added here, the links may be broken in the feature somehow but this is a place that your answer is going to live for 100000 years :)

Comment: just mentioned that the guy should include some information about the external links